# Converting Webforms to MVC: Where to put display logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, viewmodel

I'm a junior developer working with a fairly large ASP website with 100+ web forms and 100+ user controls. Our job is to converting the project to MVC5. The whole MVC concept/pattern is very interesting and right now I'm contemplating on how to make the transition as smooth as possible according to "best practice (whatever it might be).

This website is a customer portal oriented toward telephony which is heavily data driven. We fetch all data through a WCF proxy and the proxy usually returns a List of type T. For each list, we create a corresponding View Model. The View Model is populated with data and sent to the View. So far so good.

However, before the data is actually displayed, there is usually some kind of "display logic" (for lack of a better term). For example, lets assume we get back a List from the WCF proxy. PhoneLogs has certain properties, such as:

- unit price
- season
- customer name
- invoice
- id

etc.

For the PhoneLogs that belongs to customer with the 1, we want to run a Linq query that summarizes the season price according to a unit price (or whatever - just to illustrate a example).

I should add that some forms can be really complicated with lot of things going on: one form might working with 6-7 different type of Lists (that might have complex properties, such as List of ), methods which ask for data from the proxy, methods that to some kind of formatting logic before displaying it in a GridView, logic when a customer has clicked on a radio button, link, button or whatever, etc. And all this stuff is on the same user control. Just reading through the code can be really confusing. And converting all this stuff to MVC in a "proper" way is challenging.

With a large project like this, I really want to work according to some structure or pattern! My question is, where should I put in all the display logic? Should I put it directly in the controller as a helper methods? Or should the logic be part of the View Model? Or other separate files and/or directories?

Comment: Every logical function must be in BLL layer and the CRUD functions must be in DAL layer.

Comment: Display logic belongs in the view. You pass a model to the view, and the view decides how to display itself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I haven't quite understood the statement that the view should decide how to display it self.

If I pass in a model of List<PhoneLogs> to the view, and I want to display a sum of say total call time, I feel its is "wrong" to run a Linq expression in the view.

Comment: Views accept a model object, then display that model object. So in a view that displays a  `List<PhoneLogs>` it is perfectly acceptable to count the number of `PhoneLog` items in the list, because it doesn't require any additional data access to do so. so having a line like `<span>@Model.Count</span>` is alright and doesn't violate a separation of concerns principle.